# Feedback JavaFX code - MineSweeper using SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx, minesweeper

I've learned JavaFX recently (with Scene Builder) and made a MineSweeper game, would love to receive feedback and tips for improvement!
Thanks.

Below is mines class, I've commented out some lines for the GUI part to work:

```
import java.util.Random;
//import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mines {
    private int height /* rows */, width /* columns */, numMines, totalToReveal /* excluding mines */;
    public String[][] board;
    private Random rand = new Random(); // Generate random numbers
    private int h, w; // Assist with random received values
    static int winLose=-1;

    // @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public Mines(int height, int width, int numMines) {
        /* int newMines = -1; */
        // boolean checkMinesNum = false; // If number of mines is legal
        // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        /*
         * if (numMines < width * height && numMines >= 0) checkMinesNum = true; while
         * (checkMinesNum != true) {
         * System.out.println("Please enter a valid number of mines (lower than " +
         * height * width + "):"); newMines = sc.nextInt(); if (newMines < width *
         * height && newMines >= 0) { checkMinesNum = true; numMines = newMines; } } //
         * sc.close(); // Can't do, because I need to close at the end of Main class
         */
        this.numMines = numMines;
        totalToReveal = (height * width) - this.numMines;
        board = new String[height][width]; // Create game's board with nulls initialized
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) // Initialize all slots in the board
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                board[i][j] = "NF."; // Nothing ON slot, False none is revealed yet and . as default
        while (numMines != 0) {
            h = rand.nextInt(height - 1); // Generate random number for height
            w = rand.nextInt(width - 1); // Generate random number for width
            if (board[h][w].charAt(2) != 'M') { // Make sure place wasn't used before
                board[h][w] = board[h][w].substring(0, 2) + "M"; // Mark a place containing a mine with M
                numMines--;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) // Initialize slot values
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                board[i][j] = board[i][j].substring(0, 2) + get(i, j);
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return height;
    }

    private void checkPlace(int i, int j) { // Is it a legal move? (borders)
        if (i >= height || j >= width || i < 0 || j < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal move on board!");
    }

    private boolean inBoard(int i, int j) { // Is move legal? (make move or not)
        if (i >= height || j >= width || i < 0 || j < 0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addMine(int i, int j) {
        checkPlace(i, j);
        if (board[i][j].contains("M")) {
            System.out.println("Adding a mine has failed, slot already contains one!");
            return false;
        }
        board[i][j] = board[i][j].substring(0, 2) + "M";
        numMines++; // Mine was added
        totalToReveal--; // Subtract one slot (occupied by mine)
        for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) // Initialize slot values
            for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
                board[r][c] = board[r][c].substring(0, 2) + get(r, c);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean open(int i, int j) {
        checkPlace(i, j);
        if (board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T') // Already revealed
            return true;
        if (board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'M') { // Slot contains a mine (user lost)
            board[i][j] = board[i][j].substring(0, 1) + "T" + "B"; // B for boom
            totalToReveal = 0; // Finish game
            isDone();
            System.out.println("Game over, boy");
            winLose=0;
            return true;
        }
        if (board[i][j].charAt(2) != 'E' && board[i][j].charAt(2) != 'M' && board[i][j].charAt(2) != 'B') {
            board[i][j] = board[i][j].substring(0, 1) + "T" + board[i][j].substring(2, 3);
            totalToReveal--;
            if (isDone()) {
                System.out.println("You win, boy");
            winLose=1;
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'E') {
            board[i][j] = board[i][j].substring(0, 1) + "T" + board[i][j].substring(2, 3);
            totalToReveal--;
            for (int r = -1; r < 2; r++) {
                for (int c = -1; c < 2; c++) {
                    if (!(r == 0 && c == 0) && inBoard(i + r, j + c)) {
                        if (isDone()) {
                            System.out.println("You win, boy");
                        winLose=1;
                        }
                        open(i + r, j + c);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void toggleFlag(int x, int y) {
        checkPlace(x, y);
        if (board[x][y].contains("T"))
            return;
        board[x][y] = "D" + board[x][y].substring(1, 3); // Overwrite it with flag mark (D)
    }

    public void toggleQM(int x, int y) {
        checkPlace(x, y);
        if (board[x][y].contains("T"))
            return;
        board[x][y] = "?" + board[x][y].substring(1, 3); // Overwrite it with question mark (?)
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        if (totalToReveal != 0)
            return false;
        setShowAll();
        return true; // True if no more slots to reveal (won the game)
    }

    public String get(int i, int j) {
        checkPlace(i, j);
        Integer countMines = 0; // To use the object's toString method
        if (board[i][j].contains("F")) { // Slot not revealed
            if (board[i][j].contains("D")) // Slot has flag
                return "F"; // F for flag
            else if (board[i][j].contains("?")) // Slot is marked as question mark (unsure of slot's content)
                return "?";
        } // Remaining slots are revealed
        if (board[i][j].contains("M"))
            return "M";
        else {
            for (int r = -1; r < 2; r++) {
                for (int c = -1; c < 2; c++) {
                    if (!(r == 0 && c == 0) && inBoard(i + r, j + c) && board[i + r][j + c].contains("M")) {
                        countMines++;
                        if (countMines > 8 || countMines < 0)
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Something went wrong - mines count is illegal");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (countMines == 0)
            return "E";
        else
            return countMines.toString();
    }

    public void setShowAll() { // Set all slots to be revealed when game is over (win\lose)
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                if (!board[i][j].contains("T"))
                    board[i][j] = board[i][j].substring(0, 1) + "T" + board[i][j].substring(2, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
                if (board[r][c].charAt(1) == 'T')
                    s += board[r][c].substring(2, 3);
                else { // Meaning slot isn't revealed
                    if (board[r][c].contains("D") || board[r][c].contains("?"))
                        s += get(r, c);
                    else
                        s += "X";
                }
                if (c == width - 1) // New row
                    s += '\n';
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

the mainFX:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainFX extends Application {
    static Media h = new Media("https://www.mboxdrive.com/Flavour-Wataboi.mp3");
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(h);;
    static int onOoff = 0;
    static int check = 0, check2 = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1KvhFmp/menu.jpg");
            BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 720, true, true, true, true);
            BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainMenuFXML.fxml")); // fxml location
            VBox root = loader.load(); // Load layout
//          root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/menu.jpg\")");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout

//          primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

            primaryStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach"); // Set stage's title

//          primaryStage.setMinWidth(400); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//          primaryStage.setMinHeight(350);
//          primaryStage.setMaxWidth(600); // It will put constraints on the new scenes!!
//          primaryStage.setMaxHeight(450);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage
            primaryStage.show(); // Show stage
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static boolean music() {
        check = onOoff;
        check2 = check % 2;
        if (check2 == 0) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
            onOoff++;
            return true;
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            onOoff++;
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

main menu controller:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainMenuCONTROLLER {

    @FXML
    private Button NewGame;

    @FXML
    private Button QuitGame;

    @FXML
    private Button Extras;

    @FXML
    private Tooltip ExtrasTT;

    @FXML
    private Button ExtraExtras;

    @FXML
    void ExtraExtras(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1Gr7PhP/Mandalorian.png");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(100, 100, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("ExtraExtrasFXML.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = loader.load();
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/Secret.jpg\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage extrasStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        extrasStage.setTitle("Any guesses?");

//      extrasStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

        /*
         * extrasStage.setMinHeight(700); extrasStage.setMinWidth(500);
         * extrasStage.setMaxHeight(700); extrasStage.setMaxWidth(500);
         */
        extrasStage.setScene(scene);
        extrasStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void Extras(ActionEvent event) {
        Extras.setOnAction(e -> {
            boolean check = MainFX.music();
            if (check)
                Extras.setText("ON");
            else
                Extras.setText("OFF");
        });
    }

    @FXML
    void NewGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1Gr7PhP/Mandalorian.png");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 853, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("NewGameFXML.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root = loader.load();
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/Mandalorian.png\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage GameStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

//      GameStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

//      GameStage.setMinWidth(1000); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//      GameStage.setMinHeight(500);
//      GameStage.setMaxWidth(2000);
//      GameStage.setMaxHeight(1000);
        GameStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach");
        GameStage.setScene(scene);
        GameStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    void QuitGame(ActionEvent event) {
        Platform.exit(); // Quit game
    }

}
```

main menu fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MS.MainMenuCONTROLLER">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="NewGame" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#NewGame" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="New Game">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" right="10.0" top="20.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="ScoreBoard (later)">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <tooltip>
            <Tooltip contentDisplay="CENTER" height="40.0" text="In the next update..." textAlignment="CENTER" width="150.0">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Black" size="9.0" />
               </font>
            </Tooltip>
         </tooltip>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="QuitGame" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#QuitGame" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="Quit Game">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="Extras" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Extras" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="110.0" text="Check this out">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <tooltip>
                  <Tooltip fx:id="ExtrasTT" contentDisplay="CENTER" height="40.0" text="Not really..." textAlignment="CENTER" width="150.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial Black" size="9.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Tooltip>
               </tooltip>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="ExtraExtras" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ExtraExtras" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="110.0" text="Top secret">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

extra extras controller:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExtraExtrasCONTROLLER {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ExtraExtrasPIC;

    @FXML
    private Button BackMainMenu;

    @FXML
    void MainMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        
        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1KvhFmp/menu.jpg");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 720, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainMenuFXML.fxml")); // fxml location
        VBox root = loader.load(); // Load layout
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/menu.jpg\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        
//      primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

        
        primaryStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach"); // Set stage's title
//      primaryStage.setMinWidth(400); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//      primaryStage.setMinHeight(350);
//      primaryStage.setMaxWidth(600);
//      primaryStage.setMaxHeight(450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Show stage
    }

}
```

extra extras fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="ExtraExtrasPIC" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MS.ExtraExtrasCONTROLLER">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="BackMainMenu" alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="600.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#MainMenu" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Back to menu" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="65.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="365.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="600.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

new game controller:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBase;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NewGameCONTROLLER {
    static Mines game;
    static int rows, columns, mines; // To access them even when resetting board
    Button b;
    static int mouseClick = -1;

    @FXML
    private TextField NumRows;

    @FXML
    private TextField NumCols;

    @FXML
    private TextField NumM;

    @FXML
    private Button StartGame;

    @FXML
    private Button BackMainMenu;

    @FXML
    private Button RandomGame;

    @FXML
    private Button Music;

    @FXML
    void BackMainMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1KvhFmp/menu.jpg");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 720, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainMenuFXML.fxml")); // fxml location
        VBox root = loader.load(); // Load layout
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/menu.jpg\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

//      primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

        primaryStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach"); // Set stage's title
//      primaryStage.setMinWidth(400); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//      primaryStage.setMinHeight(350);
//      primaryStage.setMaxWidth(600);
//      primaryStage.setMaxHeight(450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Show stage
    }

    @FXML
    void RandomGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int low = 3, high = 15;
        int minesLow = 1, minesHigh;
        rows = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        columns = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        if (rows <= 0 || columns <= 0) {
            rows = rand.nextInt(5) + 3;
            columns = rand.nextInt(5) + 3;
        }
        minesHigh = (rows * columns) - 1;
        mines = rand.nextInt(minesHigh - minesLow) + minesLow;
        if (mines >= columns * rows)
            mines = (columns * rows) - 1;
        game = new Mines(rows, columns, mines);

        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1Gr7PhP/Mandalorian.png");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 853, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("BoardFXML.fxml")); // fxml location

        AnchorPane root = loader.load(); // Load layout
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/Mandalorian.png\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage gameStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

//      gameStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

        gameStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach"); // Set stage's title
//      gameStage.setMinWidth(1000); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//      gameStage.setMinHeight(500);
//      gameStage.setMaxWidth(2000);
//      gameStage.setMaxHeight(1000);
        gameStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage

        BoardCONTROLLER bCont = loader.getController(); // Prepare board in BoardCONTROLLER
        
        bCont.winLose.setVisible(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NewGameCONTROLLER.rows; j++) {
                b = new Button(" ");
                b.setMinSize(30, 30);
                b.setMaxSize(30, 30);
                b.setStyle("-fx-font-size:11");
                bCont.TheBoard.add(b, i, j);
                GridPane.setMargin(b, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
                GridPane.setHalignment(b, HPos.CENTER);
                GridPane.setValignment(b, VPos.CENTER);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            ((ButtonBase) bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)).setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    int x, y;
                    y = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
                    x = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
                    if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
                        game.open(x, y);
                    else if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY))
                        game.toggleFlag(x, y);
                    else if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.MIDDLE))
                        game.toggleQM(x, y);
                    for (Node child : bCont.TheBoard.getChildren()) {
                        int j = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
                        int i = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T') {
                            ((Button) child).setText(game.board[i][j].substring(2, 3));
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'F' && game.board[i][j].charAt(0) == 'D')
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/GtnDxdQ/flag.png)");
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'F' && game.board[i][j].charAt(0) == '?')
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/fnw3Hr4/QM.jpg)");
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'E') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/txvBhCS/empty.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'M') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/6Jq9S3g/mine.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'B') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/wgRt8v9/boom.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '1') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/5Gd2H0Y/1.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '2') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/GHGj0KM/2.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '3') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/sww9b1n/3.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '4') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/nrTjpqp/4.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '5') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/gZ6Rjrz/5.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '6') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/wh9XnfT/6.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '7') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/k1905rT/7.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '8') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/RCs2s2H/8.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (Mines.winLose==1) {
                            bCont.winLose.setVisible(true);
                            bCont.winLose.setText("YOU WIN!");
                        }
                        if (Mines.winLose==0) {
                            bCont.winLose.setVisible(true);
                            bCont.winLose.setText("YOU LOSE! Try again...");
                        }
                        Mines.winLose=-1;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        gameStage.show(); // Show stage
    }

    @FXML
    void StartGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        rows = Integer.parseInt(NumRows.getText());
        columns = Integer.parseInt(NumCols.getText());
        mines = Integer.parseInt(NumM.getText());
        game = new Mines(rows, columns, mines);

        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1Gr7PhP/Mandalorian.png");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 853, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("BoardFXML.fxml")); // fxml location

        AnchorPane root = loader.load(); // Load layout
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/Mandalorian.png\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage gameStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

//      gameStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

        gameStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach"); // Set stage's title
//      gameStage.setMinWidth(1000); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//      gameStage.setMinHeight(500);
//      gameStage.setMaxWidth(2000);
//      gameStage.setMaxHeight(1000);
        gameStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage

        BoardCONTROLLER bCont = loader.getController(); // Prepare board in BoardCONTROLLER
        
        bCont.winLose.setVisible(false);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NewGameCONTROLLER.rows; j++) {
                b = new Button(" ");
                b.setMinSize(30, 30);
                b.setMaxSize(30, 30);
                b.setStyle("-fx-font-size:11");
                bCont.TheBoard.add(b, i, j);
                GridPane.setMargin(b, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
                GridPane.setHalignment(b, HPos.CENTER);
                GridPane.setValignment(b, VPos.CENTER);
            }
        }       
        for (int i = 0; i < bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            ((ButtonBase) bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)).setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    int x, y;
                    y = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
                    x = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
                    if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
                        game.open(x, y);
                    else if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY))
                        game.toggleFlag(x, y);
                    else if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.MIDDLE))
                        game.toggleQM(x, y);
                    for (Node child : bCont.TheBoard.getChildren()) {
                        int j = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
                        int i = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T') {
                            ((Button) child).setText(game.board[i][j].substring(2, 3));
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'F' && game.board[i][j].charAt(0) == 'D')
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/GtnDxdQ/flag.png)");
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'F' && game.board[i][j].charAt(0) == '?')
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/fnw3Hr4/QM.jpg)");
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'E') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/txvBhCS/empty.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'M') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/6Jq9S3g/mine.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'B') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/wgRt8v9/boom.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '1') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/5Gd2H0Y/1.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '2') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/GHGj0KM/2.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '3') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/sww9b1n/3.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '4') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/nrTjpqp/4.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '5') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/gZ6Rjrz/5.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '6') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/wh9XnfT/6.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '7') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/k1905rT/7.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '8') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/RCs2s2H/8.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (Mines.winLose==1) {
                            bCont.winLose.setVisible(true);
                            bCont.winLose.setText("YOU WIN!");
                        }
                        if (Mines.winLose==0) {
                            bCont.winLose.setVisible(true);
                            bCont.winLose.setText("YOU LOSE! Try again...");
                        }
                        Mines.winLose=-1;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        gameStage.show(); // Show stage
    }

    @FXML
    void Music(ActionEvent event) {
        Music.setOnAction(e -> {
            boolean check = MainFX.music();
            if (check)
                Music.setText("ON");
            else
                Music.setText("OFF");
        });
    }

}
```

new game fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="853.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MS.NewGameCONTROLLER">
   <children>
      <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="171.0" prefWidth="980.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="444.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <children>
            <Text fill="RED" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="You can finally go on your long awaited vacation!!" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" top="20.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text fill="RED" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="The resort is just across the beach" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" top="20.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <Text fill="RED" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="DANGER! You entered BOOM Beach... You know what to do..." textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="25.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="30.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="396.0" layoutY="205.0" prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="980.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="205.0">
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="979.0">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Number of rows:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
                  <TextField fx:id="NumRows" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="137.0" promptText="2 and above">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="10.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="979.0">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Number of columns:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
                  <TextField fx:id="NumCols" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="117.0" promptText="2 and above">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="10.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="979.0">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Number of mines:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
                  <TextField fx:id="NumM" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="133.0" promptText="1 and above">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="10.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="979.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="StartGame" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#StartGame" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="Start" textFill="RED">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="979.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="BackMainMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#BackMainMenu" prefHeight="30.0" text="Back to menu">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="RandomGame" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#RandomGame" prefHeight="30.0" text="Random board" textFill="RED">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
            <Button fx:id="Music" alignment="TOP_CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Music" prefHeight="30.0" text="Music">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font size="16.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets right="1.0" />
         </padding>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

board controller:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBase;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BoardCONTROLLER {
    Button b;

    @FXML
    public GridPane TheBoard;
    
    @FXML
    public Label winLose;

    @FXML
    private Button BackMenu;

    @FXML
    private Button Music;

    @FXML
    private Button ResetBoard;

    @FXML
    void BackMenu(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1KvhFmp/menu.jpg");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 720, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainMenuFXML.fxml")); // fxml location
        VBox root = loader.load(); // Load layout
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/menu.jpg\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

//      primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

        primaryStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach"); // Set stage's title
//      primaryStage.setMinWidth(400); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//      primaryStage.setMinHeight(350);
//      primaryStage.setMaxWidth(600);
//      primaryStage.setMaxHeight(450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Show stage
    }

    @FXML
    void Music(ActionEvent event) {
        Music.setOnAction(e -> {
            boolean check = MainFX.music();
            if (check)
                Music.setText("ON");
            else
                Music.setText("OFF");
        });
    }

    @FXML
    void ResetBoard(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Image backgroundColor = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/1Gr7PhP/Mandalorian.png");
        BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(1280, 853, true, true, true, true);
        BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

        NewGameCONTROLLER.game = new Mines(NewGameCONTROLLER.rows, NewGameCONTROLLER.columns, NewGameCONTROLLER.mines);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); // Create loading object
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("BoardFXML.fxml")); // fxml location

        AnchorPane root = loader.load(); // Load layout
//      root.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"file:///C:/EclipseProjects/MineSweeper/src/MS/Mandalorian.png\")");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); // Create scene with chosen layout
        Stage gameStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

//      gameStage.setFullScreen(true);
        root.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

        gameStage.setTitle("BOOM Beach"); // Set stage's title
//      gameStage.setMinWidth(1000); // Won't be allowed to make width/height smaller
//      gameStage.setMinHeight(500);
//      gameStage.setMaxWidth(2000);
//      gameStage.setMaxHeight(1000);
        gameStage.setScene(scene); // Set scene to stage

        BoardCONTROLLER bCont = loader.getController(); // Prepare board in BoardCONTROLLER
        
        bCont.winLose.setVisible(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < NewGameCONTROLLER.columns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NewGameCONTROLLER.rows; j++) {
                b = new Button(" ");
                b.setMinSize(30, 30);
                b.setMaxSize(30, 30);
                b.setStyle("-fx-font-size:11");
                bCont.TheBoard.add(b, i, j);
                GridPane.setMargin(b, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
                GridPane.setHalignment(b, HPos.CENTER);
                GridPane.setValignment(b, VPos.CENTER);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            ((ButtonBase) bCont.TheBoard.getChildren().get(i)).setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    int x, y;
                    y = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
                    x = (int) ((Button) event.getSource()).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
                    if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
                        NewGameCONTROLLER.game.open(x, y);
                    else if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY))
                        NewGameCONTROLLER.game.toggleFlag(x, y);
                    else if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.MIDDLE))
                        NewGameCONTROLLER.game.toggleQM(x, y);
                    for (Node child : bCont.TheBoard.getChildren()) {
                        int j = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-column");
                        int i = (int) ((Button) child).getProperties().get("gridpane-row");
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T') {
                            ((Button) child).setText(NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].substring(2, 3));
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'F' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(0) == 'D')
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/GtnDxdQ/flag.png)");
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'F' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(0) == '?')
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/fnw3Hr4/QM.jpg)");
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'E') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/txvBhCS/empty.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'M') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/6Jq9S3g/mine.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == 'B') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/wgRt8v9/boom.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '1') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/5Gd2H0Y/1.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '2') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/GHGj0KM/2.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '3') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/sww9b1n/3.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '4') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/nrTjpqp/4.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '5') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/gZ6Rjrz/5.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '6') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/wh9XnfT/6.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '7') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/k1905rT/7.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(1) == 'T' && NewGameCONTROLLER.game.board[i][j].charAt(2) == '8') {
                            ((Button) child).setStyle(
                                    "-fx-background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/RCs2s2H/8.jpg)");
                            ((Button) child).setText(" ");
                        }
                        if (Mines.winLose==1) {
                            bCont.winLose.setVisible(true);
                            bCont.winLose.setText("YOU WIN!");
                        }
                        if (Mines.winLose==0) {
                            bCont.winLose.setVisible(true);
                            bCont.winLose.setText("YOU LOSE! Try again...");
                        }
                        Mines.winLose=-1;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        gameStage.show(); // Show stage }
    }
}
```

board fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MS.BoardCONTROLLER">
   <children>
        <GridPane fx:id="TheBoard" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="90.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        </GridPane>
             <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" fillHeight="false" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="560.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="700.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="560.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="BackMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#BackMenu" text="Back to menu" />
            <Button fx:id="ResetBoard" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ResetBoard" text="Reset" textFill="RED">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="Music" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Music" text="Music">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Label fx:id="winLose" layoutX="796.0" layoutY="535.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="200.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="35.0" />
         </font>
         <textFill>
            <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0">
               <stops>
                  <Stop color="RED" />
                  <Stop color="#00e1ff" offset="1.0" />
               </stops>
            </LinearGradient>
         </textFill>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: We don't have the images that you link to in the program. You need to either replace them with images that are posted online, or else you need to modify the code to not use them.

Comment: Done, uploaded them